# How to configure Jmeter for 1 hour endurance test?

Tags: concurrency, jmeter, hour

We have a requirement to run test for exactly 1 hour with 5000 users.

How may I configure in jmeter with exactly 5000 users in 1 hour?

Answer (score 1):

First will try if this could be achieved with a [single machine](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter) available to you.

1. You need to create the users in advance or create them before the
   test within a [Setup Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group).
2. Create a CSV file with the 5000 users' credentials
3. Read the data from the CSV file using [CSV Data Set config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element
4. Pass the user credentials to the login requests ${username} ${password}
5. Configure the main Thread Group to run the test for one hour. Threads 5000, Rampup time 120 seconds, Duration 3720 seconds

[image]

JMeter should be optimised to run large number of users.

1. Use JMeter listeners for debugging purposes only
2. Run JMeter performance tests in non-GUI mode
3. Increase JMeter heap space to generate a larger load
4. Use LAN instead of a Wi-Fi connection when running a load test
5. Save test results in CSV format and save only required information

If you cannot emulate 5000 with a single JMeter instance. You will have to distribute the users to multiple JMeter instances (JMeter servers/Load agents ) running on different client machines. Also you can run your test from a JMeter on cloud services like [Redline13](https://www.redline13.com) or [Blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com).

If you have time and client machines available you can go for setting up a JMeter distributed testing environment.

JMeter distributed testing : [Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

Answer (score 0):

The relevant configuration for the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) would be something like:

[image]

If you have troubles with defining the workload, ramp-up, ramp-down periods, time to hold the load, etc. you may find [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) easier to use, for example here is the equivalent configuration for the [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup):

[image]

These custom Thread Groups can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup):

[image]